# Proof by induction in Relations

Tags: induction, relations

$R$ and $S$ be relations such that $R\subseteq S$. Prove that $R^n \subseteq S^n$ for all positive integers.Can anyone help me in proving this using induction?

Comment: What does Rn mean?

Comment: @HenrySwanson sorry for the typo.Hope u understood it now!!

Comment: I'm still not sure. Is it an $n$-ary relation, or is it "composing" $R$ with itself $n$ times?

Comment: It is an n-ary relation where n is supposed to be any positive integer.

Comment: So $R$ and $S$ have to be transitive? (sorry, I'm just not familiar with that notation)

Comment: No they are just relations with R being a subset of S!!

Comment: Okay, I'm just going to assume that by $R^n$ you mean $R^{n-1} R$. And by $RS$ you mean $(x,y)$ such that there is a $z$ where $(x,z) \in R$ and $(z, y) \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

So your base case, $n = 1$ is easy.

Say $R^n \subseteq S^n$. You want to show that if $R^{n+1} \subseteq S^{n+1}$. Pick an $(x,y) \in R^{n+1}$. By the definition of $R^{n+1}$, there is a $z$ such that $(x,z) \in R^n$ and $(z,y) \in R$. Now use your induction hypothesis.

(I assumed your definition of $R^n$ is composition, not $n$-ary, because frankly, what you said doesn't make sense)

Comment: could you please finish it!! I couldnt get through it!!

Comment: Since $(z,y)$ is in $R$, what else do you know about $(z,y)$?

Comment: Also, there's only one statement on which you could use the induction hypothesis ($R^n \subseteq S^n$). Can you find it?